# Are there any keepassx like solutions for OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

Are there any password protecting solutions under OpenBSD, that is not from Ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. This is precisely what a port or package is for, and KeePassX is available as a port and as a package.